# Function for prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there a  a function for calculating nth prime number?
A near approximate answer would also do as I need for numbers below 1000.

Comment: There are only 168 primes below 1000, so a lookup table might be best and simplest

Comment: Being curious, still if i need bigger numbers

Answer (score 3):

Get $1^{st}$ 1000 primes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers)

From wiki:

> There is no known efficient formula to calculate $n^{th}$ prime number.
>    For example, ***there is no non-constant polynomial, even in several variables, that takes only prime values.***
>   However, there are numerous expressions that do encode all primes, or only primes.
>    One possible formula is based on *Wilson's theorem* and generates the number 2 many times and all other primes exactly once.

There is also a set of **Diophantine equations** in nine variables and one parameter with the following property:

*The parameter is prime if and only if the resulting system of equations has a solution over the natural numbers. This can be used to obtain a single formula with the property that all its positive values are prime.*

Comment: See also [the polynomial of Jones, et al.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548521/18398)